# How to center a div automatically when another div is hidden

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Firstly I placed two `div`s in the center of another `div`, everything is fine.
My other requirement now is to center the first `div` automatically when my second `div`, which is beside the first `div`, is hidden: if I hide my other `div`, then automatically the first `div` should be aligned in the center.

The problem is that it is not adjusting automatically to the center. Is there any way  to solve this?

Here is my html code.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
<div class="col-md-6" style="height:35%;background-color:red;width:35%;;margin-left:15%;margin-right:auto;">
  <label>First div</label>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6" style="height:35%;background-color:yellow;width:35%;margin-left:5%;" >
    <label>Second div</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrap those two divs in a single div and give `margin: 0 auto`. or give the divs `display: inline-block` and give the parent element `text-align: center`. Ofcourse in both the ways, you should remove the side margins to those divs.

Comment: when your one div hides, apply a class dynamically which contains the attributes which will position your another div to center.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with KK, but please make sure to remove the float that bootstrap adds:

```
.row div{
    float:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/721/

Answer (score 1):

Try this I have given a pure bootstrap solution 
http://www.bootply.com/fVdBLnSZI4

more detail output here: http://output.jsbin.com/fezat/101

Comment: my requirement is regarding centering the first div when second div is hidden

Comment: Use display: none; instead of visibility: hidden; it will work

Answer (score 0):

you will have to dynamically change the class of the non-disappearing div to `col-md-12`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your css:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.row {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.row .col-md-6:first-child {
    height:35%;
    background-color:red;
    width:35%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.row .col-md-6:last-child {
    height:35%;
    background-color:yellow;
    width:35%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

To hide, just use `display:none`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/717/

Comment: Thanks for  your reply , if i try your code it is not working properly in my html page but in fiddler it is cool ,  i dont know why...

Comment: Maybe, you have some other css which affects this. Try removing other css which affects it

Comment: And also hiding the div is depending upon my code in java script.

Comment: That's not an issue. You can hide it using js by selecting the div

Comment: I just simply took normal html page and placed everything which you have provided.

Comment: @Meena try the demo i have provided, and don't forget to include jquery js

Comment: If it works in fiddle but not in your page, then  definitely there is issue with the page. Can you share more information regarding that page?

Answer (score 0):

Should do following

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($("#a").css("display") == 'none') {
    $("#b").addClass("a1");

  }
})
```

```css
.a1 {
  margin: 0% 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" style="display:none;">
  abc
</div>
<div id="b">
  xyz
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove "col-md-6" dynamically and add `margin:0 auto` to your css of second div.
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vod0qebj/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just see this fiddle
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qjqj8ee/)

```
.parent {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.first_div {
    height:35%;
    border: 3px solid green ;
    width:35%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 20%;
}
.second_div {
    height:35%;
    border: 3px solid red;
    width:35%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/Ashu2990/kv99no1g/

html

```
<div id="a"  class="css">A</div>
<div id="b" class="css">B</div>
</br>
<button id="hideDiv">Hide</button>
```

css

```
.css{
width:50%; 
height:100px; 
float:left; 
display:inline-block;
text-align: center;
}

.css1{
    width:50%; 
    height:100px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

javascript

```
$("#hideDiv").click(function(){
    $("#b").hide();
       console.log($("#b"));
        $('#a').removeClass("css").addClass("css1");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that "without" JS (only to make a div dissapear)
The `display:flex;` will relocate the content to the center **automatically**.

```js
$('.container > div').on('click', function() {
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container > div {
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50%;
}
.container > div:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I used display: none one the divs i was was trying to center and it worked. To switch between states use display: unset.